# Center Justify paragraph in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I use a RichTextBox, and I want to format all the lines in a paragraph with justify alignment, except the last line will be aligned to the center.

as this:

```
      sssssssssssssssssssssssss
      sssssssssssssssssssssssss
      sssssssssssssssssssssssss
           ssssssssssssss
```

I use [this code](http://geekswithblogs.net/pvidler/archive/2003/10/14/182.aspx) for justify alignment.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? toda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is "center justify".  Modify the enum, it's #5 below:

```
/// <summary>
/// Specifies how text in a <see cref="AdvRichTextBox"/> is
/// horizontally aligned.
/// </summary>
public enum TextAlign
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The text is aligned to the left.
    /// </summary>
    Left = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// The text is aligned to the right.
    /// </summary>
    Right = 2,

    /// <summary>
    /// The text is aligned in the center.
    /// </summary>
    Center = 3,

    /// <summary>
    /// The text is justified.
    /// </summary>
    Justify = 4,

    /// <summary>
    /// The text is center justified.
    /// </summary>
    CenterJustify = 5
}
```

[image]

Sample code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AdvRichTextBox tb = new AdvRichTextBox();

    tb.SelectionAlignment = TextAlign.CenterJustify;
    tb.SelectedText = "Here is a justified paragraph. It will show up justified using the new AdvRichTextBox control created by who knows.\n";

    tb.Width = 250;
    tb.Height = 450;

    this.Controls.Add(tb);
}
```

Comment: +1 this is probably the right answer :) (I admit I had a lot of difficulties in understanding the OP goal...)

Comment: First of all, thanks. Secondly, on my computer it formats the entire paragraph to the center. why is that?  (NB. And difficulties are because of me, I do not know English well)

Comment: @user1543998 - It should be "Center Justified", so the entire paragraph is both centered AND justified.  If you're not seeing the "justified" part, I'm not sure on that.  Make sure you're passing in a 5 for the "CenterJustify".  FYI... I'm using Windows 7 / Visual Studio 2010

Comment: @user1543998 - also, try changing your font to courier new for testing.  Fonts have different widths for characters, and if you see my example, there is a tiny bit of white space on either side of the second line.  It's justified, but also centered.  You will not be able to achieve "left justified" combined with "center justified".

Comment: Yes, I'm passing in a 5 for the "CenterJustify". and I'm working on VS 2010 express, and Windows xp. and I see your example, it very good, but on my computer it makes center alignment. and I tried to change the font, and it did not help.

Comment: @user1543998 - it could be Windows XP.  Maybe "Center Justify" is defined as something else in XP.  Try 6, 7, 8, etc. to see how it reacts.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RichTextBox>
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph TextAlignment="Justify">
                    sssssssssssssssssssssssss
                    sssssssssssssssssssssssss
                    sssssssssssssssssssssssss
                </Paragraph>
                <Paragraph TextAlignment="Center">
                    sssssssssssssssssssssssss
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Mainly using Paragraph TextAlignment will give you the option to align the text: 1. Justify, 2. Center, 3. Left, 4. Right;

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion  Robert Columbia